# Is there any way of clearing cache and free up space from android using appium python?

Tags: browser-cache, appium-android, python-appium, appium-desktop, android-chrome

I run an app and from the app it directs me to chrome for login. After which I give my email and password and then after successful login I get redirected to app. Now the question is in case I need to run it again I need to manually clear the cache and free up space every time login happens and this does not allow me to run all codes in one stretch. Can you please let me know is there a way to automate clearing cache and free up space using python and appium.I run my code on ubuntu os platform.

Comment: have you tried using `driver.resetApp()`?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add `adb shell pm clear packageName` to your test file wherever you need and try